# Browser redirect recources from http (relative path) to https

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nginx, https

Problem:
When i go to my local website, all content load over https. And i Receive this error.

I do request to http://c.gaz.dec04/ - it's on my local machine
[image]

but all recourses load over https and i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
[image]

[image]

I use my win 11 machine to build my app, and then i use WSL Ubuntu to store my websites.
On hosting and other LAMP servers (Openserver etc all work fine, but on local not work)

Complete scheme: Win 11 (build app) -> WSL Ubuntu (store dist) -> Nginx (hosted to http://c.gaz.dec04)

How to fix it?

I delete rules from hsts chrome, same result.

My file inside sites-available/enable

```
  1 server {
  2     listen 80;
  3     #listen 443;
  4     server_name c.gaz.dec04 www.c.gaz.dec04;
  5     root /var/www/c.gaz.dec04/html/;
  6
  7     index index.html index.htm index.php;
  8
  9     #ssl off;
 10
 11     #proxy_redirect off;
 12
 13     location / {
 14         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 15     }
 16
 17     location ~ \.php$ {
 18         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 19         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 20      }
 21
 22     location ~ /\.ht {
 23         deny all;
 24     }
 25
 26 }
```

Expected result:
All content (as *.css, *.js etc) load over http

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i will try answer on my question. In my case problem was in tag **meta**, inside **head** tag. I comment this string, and all works.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Thanks for watching.